# Android Studio shows errors in layout.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm using data binding library and I experience following issues in Android Studio 3.0:

somelayout.xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="meeting"
            type="some.package.MeetingStatusResponse"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{meeting.title}"
            tools:text="Title"
            />


            ...


    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

In this place: `android:text="@{meeting.title}"` Android Studio 3.0 underlines the @ symbol and informs about error:

```
Error:(29, 27) <expr> or <lambda expression> expected, got '@'
```

Model class is written in Kotlin if it has any relevance.
The code completion is also not working for bound classes. **The application can be successfully build using both, gradle command and Android Studio run app button. So this is just editor issue**.

I observe this issue on Mac. On Windows it works ok. I do not have more computers to check if it's platform related issue.

Comment: what do you want to display in the textView @piotrpo

Comment: That's just ordinary String.

Comment: you want to display "@" too in the string right

Comment: No, this is a data binding so "@{expression}" means that this is a code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to add in gradle `compileOptions` ?

```
    `sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7`
    `targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7`
```

Comment: I'm afraid, that's not the reason. This issue as I wrote is machine dependent.